# Passing config parameters to HtmlEditor

Tags: extjs6-classic

I found this nice and elegant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65189648/12278292 View [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aoa) to include an HtmlEditor in a Picker list (since v6 grid cells doesn't support it as editor). My question is: how to pass configuration parameters to the HtmlEditor? In the example, it has `enableFonts` set to `false`, but how to pass boolean values to it for more config options (enableLinks, enableFormat, etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your criteria for choosing the config parameters? Does it depend on cell value or column? Or something else?

Comment: It's alleatory: i.e. in some cells only `enableFormat` should be available (all other parameters should be false then), in other ones you could make lists, etc. All in all it's around 7 parameters, and the solution should be flexible enough to configure eacho one of them.